# Xamarin Forms ios database not being deployed

Tags: ios, sqlite, xamarin.forms

Within the Xamarin Forms solution.  I have a sqlite database inside the AppName.iOS project  Resources folder. This is a db with many tables and records in each table.

I am trying to load it using the following:

```
 public SQLiteAsyncConnection GetConnection()
        {
            var documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Resources);
            var path = Path.Combine(documentsPath, "InfoDb.sqlite");
            return new SQLiteAsyncConnection(path);
        }
```

When I navigate to the "path" for the db, the file is not there. Where should the preloaded database be located in the project?

Comment: Resources are not files.  If you want to open a read-only database that is deployed with your app, add it to your project with `Build Action  = Content` and then you can open if as a file.

Comment: I would also like to be able to write to it. Should the db be placed elsewhere?

Comment: the app bundle is not writable at run time.  You will need to copy the db file from the app bundle to a writable folder when your app starts